# JmsTemplate - define concurrency per queue?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

So far i've only been able to find concurrency setting in the jms connection factory:

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="myConnectionFactory"
                    task-executor="myTaskExecutor"
                    destination-resolver="myDestinationResolver"
                    transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"
                    concurrency="10">
```

Is it possible to configure the number of consumers for a single queue? i.e something like:

```
    <jms:listener destination="playerStatsQueue" ref="playerStatsService"
        method="onMessage" concurrency="100" />
```

Thanks!~

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I have a specific queue I would like to tweak the amount of consumers for it

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the namespace but an abstract parent `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and create one child instance per listener. That way you can tweak all the properties you need.

```
<bean id="parentContainer" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="playerStatsListener parent="parentContainer">
    <property name="destination" ref="playerStatsQueue"/>
    <property name="listener" ref="playerStatsService"/> 
    <property name="concurrency" value="100"/>         
</bean>
```