# How to configure concurrency to a single queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I would like to configure number of consumers for a single queue in jms template. I tried to implement this: [JmsTemplate - define concurrency per queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860195/jmstemplate-define-concurrency-per-queue/21865846?noredirect=1#21865846) but in the ActiveMQQueue is stiil shows 1.
my messanging context:

```
<bean id="parentContainer" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="parentContainer" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="playerStatsListener" parent="parentContainer">
        <property name="destination" ref="playerStatsQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="playerStatsService" />
        <property name="concurrency" value="100" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Listeners -->
    <bean id="playerStatsService" class="com.XXX.service.PlayerStatsService" />
    <!-- Destinations -->
        <bean id="playerStatsQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="playerStatsQueue" />
```

another related question: Is there a difference between the "listener" to "messageListener" property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can set `concurrentConsumers` and `maxConcurrentConsumers` on the [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setConcurrentConsumers%28int%29). The `concurrency` setting gives this as a convenient range.

But according to the docs

> Specify concurrency limits via a "lower-upper" String, e.g. "5-10", or
>   a simple upper limit String, e.g. "10" (the lower limit will be 1 in
>   this case).

So if you just say `concurrency=100`, it's still equivalent to `1-100`, which would explain why you're seeing 1 consumer.

Comment: Thank I just figure it out myself :) . So my solution is to have several  jms:listener-container with different concurrency. is this seems OK?

Comment: I've never had that use case, but from the other answers you posted, that seems like the way to do it. :)